# On Access, How do I Query like if 3 or more fields are 'True' then show the record?

Tags: database, microsoft-access

Is there a way to run a query to show records that have 3 or more check box fields selected?

Answer (score 0):

This would be horribly complicated in SQL, basically requiring querying
all the 3-columns combinations.

For A, B, C, D, you would have something like this pseudo-code:

```
(A and B and C) or (A and B and D) or (B and C and D) or (A and C and D)
```

Comment: Ah I see. I would possibly end up having over 100 fields so that's a lot of possible combinations. Thanks for the info!